# Populate ListView only once on fragment with SlidingMenu android

Tags: android, listview, fragment, slidingmenu

I'm new on android developing, and I'm developing an app with SlidingMenu library from jfeinstein10, and i'm listing some top rated data on main screen...
Now i'm doing this by getting data from SQLite and putting on a ListView inside a fragment activity

HomeFragment

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);
    new ManageSQLiteResponse((ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv_top_rate)).execute();

    return rootView;
}
```

ManagerSQLiteResponse call:

```
public void updateList(ListView listView){
    DietsListAdapter adapter = new DietsListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.single_top_rate, dietList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And every time i switch the fragment by selecting on SlidingMenu, all the ListView is populated again, and it causes some lag, and the menu won't open or close smoothly...

So, is there some way to run AsyncTask.execute() and populate the ListView only once, and not every time the fragment is created? by this i think it will stop lagging the SlidingMenu

TVM

Comment: try to store fragments in backstack.

Comment: can you explain me how i do that? i'm kind new to all this thing

Answer (score 0):

use this method to add fragment in your container layout.

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

    Fragment fragmentPopped = manager.findFragmentByTag(backStateName) ;

    if ( fragmentPopped != null ) 
        manager.popBackStack(backStateName, 0);
    else
        ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);

    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
    ft.commit();
}
```

and look make a condition in code like this, if

```
if ( adapter.getCount() > 0 )
{
   // dont add listview.setadapter() method here.
}
elsse
{
   // load data in listview.
}
```

Comment: I'm switching between fragments like this:

 public void switchContent(Fragment fragment) {
  this.fragment = fragment;
   
  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
  getSlidingMenu().showContent();
 }

Is there some edit i can make here?

Comment: if you will not add fragment to backstack it will created everytime